# EditingTextController updates widget value without calling setState() - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This might be not technical question,however, I read that whenever you want to change **StatefullWidget** state you need to call **setState()** function. i gave a test for **EditText()** widget and use the **EditingTextController** as widget controller, i called the  `controller.text = "some text"`from user-defined function without calling `setState()` function and the value of the **EditText()** changed to be **some text** !

i would like to know how this done? i read the documentation and it says `EditingTextController` will change the value of the widget but we already know that in order to change 
**State Full Widget** state you need to call `setState()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of this is true. But to change the state in Flutter you have other options, and `setState(() {});` is only one of them. Another option is to create `Notifier -> listener`, then set the listener to listen for the Notifier, like this `TextFormField(controller: _controller,...)` **so any update on the Notifier(controller), will notify the listener(TextFormField) to update itself.**

e.g:

```dart
//...
final _controller = TextEditingController();
//...
child: TextFormField(
    controller: _controller,
    decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
),
```

in this example:

- **_controller**: is a ChangeNotifier.
- **TextFormField**: is a listener to this ChangeNotifier(_controller).

and once you call this `_controller.text=..` the _controller (which is consider as **ChangeNotifier** [see this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController/text.html).) ***"will notify all the listeners of this TextEditingController that they need to update"***, so it will give you same result as using `setState(() {});` or `Stream/StreamBuilder` or `Future/FutureBuilder`...etc.